IntelliJ crashing since latest update
This morning IntelliJ got updated from version 2023.3 to 2024.1 and since then it doesn't work anymore. I am using Ubuntu 22.04.
When I try to run it, it opens for a few seconds, and then ALL currently running apps other than the terminal are closed.
I can't see anything particuarly interesting in idea.log:
[removed this very long log from the question because it did not contain anything related to the issue]


I tried:

Rebooting the computer
Uninstalling and reinstalling IntelliJ
Downloading and running IntelliJ 2023.3 again
Disabling the OOM killer: How do I disable the systemd OOM process killer in Ubuntu 22.04?
Renaming the IntelliJ Configuration/Plugins/System directories as listed here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs?page=3

The only thing that kind-of worked was running IntelliJ as root instead of as myself, but I don't want to do it unless it's the last resort.
Then I looked at /var/log/syslog and in there I found this:
systemd[3656]: Started snap.intellij-idea-ultimate.intellij-idea-ultimate-f57e7f9d-943c-4fd7-a013-2536fe031f75.scope.
gnome-shell[45831]: malloc(): unaligned tcache chunk detected
gnome-shell[45831]: (EE)
gnome-shell[45831]: (EE) Backtrace:
gnome-shell[45831]: (EE) 0: /usr/bin/Xwayland (0x5a5623050000+0x165369) [0x5a56231b5369]
gnome-shell[45831]: (EE) 1: /usr/bin/Xwayland (0x5a5623050000+0x165472) [0x5a56231b5472]
gnome-shell[45831]: (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7aa585e00000+0x42520) [0x7aa585e42520]
gnome-shell[45831]: (EE) 3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (pthread_kill+0x12c) [0x7aa585e969fc]
gnome-shell[45831]: (EE) 4: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (raise+0x16) [0x7aa585e42476]
gnome-shell[45831]: (EE) 5: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (abort+0xd3) [0x7aa585e287f3]
gnome-shell[45831]: (EE) 6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7aa585e00000+0x89676) [0x7aa585e89676]
gnome-shell[45831]: (EE) 7: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7aa585e00000+0xa0cfc) [0x7aa585ea0cfc]
gnome-shell[45831]: (EE) 8: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7aa585e00000+0xa53dc) [0x7aa585ea53dc]
gnome-shell[45831]: (EE) 9: /usr/bin/Xwayland (0x5a5623050000+0xf9d92) [0x5a5623149d92]
gnome-shell[45831]: (EE) 10: /usr/bin/Xwayland (0x5a5623050000+0xa72ce) [0x5a56230f72ce]
gnome-shell[45831]: (EE) 11: /usr/bin/Xwayland (0x5a5623050000+0x34c63) [0x5a5623084c63]
gnome-shell[45831]: (EE) 12: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7aa585e00000+0x29d90) [0x7aa585e29d90]
gnome-shell[45831]: (EE) 13: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0x80) [0x7aa585e29e40]
gnome-shell[45831]: (EE) 14: /usr/bin/Xwayland (0x5a5623050000+0x36495) [0x5a5623086495]
gnome-shell[45831]: (EE)
gnome-shell[45831]: (EE)
gnome-shell[45831]: Fatal server error:
gnome-shell[45831]: (EE) Caught signal 6 (Aborted). Server aborting
gnome-shell[45831]: (EE)
gnome-shell[3923]: Connection to xwayland lost
pulseaudio[3715]: X11 I/O error handler called
google-chrome.desktop[45806]: [45913:45913:0405/133205.156084:ERROR:connection.cc(61)] X connection error received.
pulseaudio[3715]: X11 I/O error exit handler called, preparing to tear down X11 modules
gnome-shell[3923]: X Wayland crashed; attempting to recover
systemd[3656]: Stopped target GNOME session X11 services.
systemd[3656]: Stopping GNOME XSettings service...
systemd[3656]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
gnome-shell[3923]: Using public X11 display :0, (using :1 for managed services)
systemd[3656]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[3656]: Stopped GNOME XSettings service.
systemd[3656]: Stopped target GNOME session X11 services.
systemd[3656]: app-gnome-google\x2dchrome-45799.scope: Consumed 5.204s CPU time.
systemd[3656]: snap.intellij-idea-ultimate.intellij-idea-ultimate-f57e7f9d-943c-4fd7-a013-2536fe031f75.scope: Consumed 26.830s CPU time.

Since Wayland was mentioned in the stack trace I tried disabling it as described here: https://jumpcloud.com/support/troubleshooting-remote-assist-disable-wayland-or-gpu-rendering-for-linux
This only made the problem worse because in addition to all the apps crashing, i now also had to sign back into Ubuntu after the crash.
The new stack trace was quite similar:
intellij-idea-ultimate_intellij-idea-ultimate.desktop[70499]: 2024-04-05 13:59:13,248 [   1792]   WARN - #c.i.s.ComponentManagerImpl - com.intellij.platform.ide.menu.GlobalMenuLinux <clinit> requests com.intellij.openapi.application.Experiments instance. Class initialization must not depend on services. Consider using instance of the service on-demand instead.
intellij-idea-ultimate_intellij-idea-ultimate.desktop[70499]: 2024-04-05 13:59:13,521 [   2065]   WARN - #c.i.e.t.TargetBasedSdks - SDK target configuration data is absent
intellij-idea-ultimate_intellij-idea-ultimate.desktop[70499]: 2024-04-05 13:59:13,526 [   2070]   WARN - #c.i.e.t.TargetBasedSdks - SDK target configuration data is absent
intellij-idea-ultimate_intellij-idea-ultimate.desktop[70499]: 2024-04-05 13:59:13,527 [   2071]   WARN - #c.i.e.t.TargetBasedSdks - SDK target configuration data is absent
intellij-idea-ultimate_intellij-idea-ultimate.desktop[70499]: 2024-04-05 13:59:14,056 [   2600]   WARN - #c.i.u.x.Binding - No accessors for java.awt.Color. This means that state class cannot be serialized properly. Please see https://jb.gg/ij-psoc
intellij-idea-ultimate_intellij-idea-ultimate.desktop[70499]: 2024-04-05 13:59:14,895 [   3439]   WARN - #c.i.s.ComponentManagerImpl - com.github.copilot.platform.state.ToolWindowRegistrationSettings <clinit> requests com.github.copilot.platform.state.ToolWindowRegistrationSettings instance. Class initialization must not depend on services. Consider using instance of the service on-demand in>
systemd[3656]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 138.
systemd[3656]: Stopped Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
systemd[3656]: Started Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
snapd-desktop-i[70805]: Failed to do gtk init. Waiting for a new session with desktop capabilities.
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: malloc(): unaligned tcache chunk detected
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: (EE)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: (EE) Backtrace:
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (OsLookupColor+0x139) [0x5b8231699ab9]
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: (EE) 1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__sigaction+0x50) [0x7d49e1a42520]
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (pthread_kill+0x12c) [0x7d49e1a969fc]
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: (EE) 3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (raise+0x16) [0x7d49e1a42476]
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: (EE) 4: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (abort+0xd3) [0x7d49e1a287f3]
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: (EE) 5: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__fsetlocking+0x426) [0x7d49e1a89676]
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: (EE) 6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (timer_settime+0x2cc) [0x7d49e1aa0cfc]
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: (EE) 7: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (malloc+0x33c) [0x7d49e1aa53dc]
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: (EE) 8: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (SetGlyphPicture+0x15d) [0x5b82315f311d]
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: (EE) 9: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (AddTraps+0x347a) [0x5b82315fb8da]
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: (EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (SendErrorToClient+0x365) [0x5b8231523635]
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: (EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitFonts+0x3c4) [0x5b82315276b4]
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: (EE) 12: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_init_first+0x90) [0x7d49e1a29d90]
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: (EE) 13: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0x80) [0x7d49e1a29e40]
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: (EE) 14: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x25) [0x5b8231510605]
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: (EE)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: (EE)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: Fatal server error:
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: (EE) Caught signal 6 (Aborted). Server aborting
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: (EE)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: (EE)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: #011 at http://wiki.x.org
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]:  for help.
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/jgosar/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: (EE)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
snapd-desktop-i[70805]: Checking session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_325...
snapd-desktop-i[70805]: Is a desktop session! Forcing a reload.
snapd-desktop-i[70805]: Loop exited. Forcing reload.
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[55967]: (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.

/home/jgosar/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log didn't contain any useful info at all
Does anybody have any tips on what else I could try?

Please submit a bug on their official Bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

I have the same problem. This problem was related to to the x11/wayland update, which was today morning. After i downgrade xserver-common, xserver-xorg-legacy, xserver-xorg-core from 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.9 to 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.8 the problem disappear.

This worked for me https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-71746/As-of-yesterday-Pycharm-and-IntelliJ-crashes-and-kills-my-Ubuntu-22.04-session

So this is what happens when bugs don't make Postgresql a tiny bit slower. Ubuntu bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/2060354

April 10 fix released for all affected Ubuntu versions. Just updated my 22.04 LTS, and problem solved, Freemind and Jetbrains IDEs work w/o crashes now.

It's not IntelliJ problem. Many more apps stopped working today (05.04.2024).
It's X11/wayland update.
While there's no patch, go back to previous versions (if you are sure nobody has access to your computer - https://auscert.org.au/bulletins/ESB-2024.2065/):
Ubuntu 22.04
cd /tmp
sudo wget https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security-proposed/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/27692766/+files/xserver-xorg-core_21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.8_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i xserver-xorg-core_21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.8_amd64.deb

sudo wget https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security-proposed/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/27692766/+files/xserver-common_21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.8_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i xserver-common_21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.8_all.deb

sudo wget https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security-proposed/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/27692760/+files/xwayland_22.1.1-1ubuntu0.11_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i xwayland_22.1.1-1ubuntu0.11_amd64.deb

Ubuntu 20.04

sudo wget https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security-proposed/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/27692773/+files/xserver-xorg-core_1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.15_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i xserver-xorg-core_1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.15_amd64.deb

sudo wget https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security-proposed/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/27692773/+files/xserver-common_1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.15_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i xserver-common_1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.15_all.deb

sudo wget https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security-proposed/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/27692773/+files/xwayland_1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.15_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i xwayland_1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.15_amd64.deb
... and reboot
Update (10.04.2024):
Fix is released. You can just "apt upgrade".
If you used my solution there can be packages versions error. To make them correct again and back to Ubuntu's original packages execute:

sudo apt update
sudo apt --fix-broken upgrade


May I use timeshift to roll back the last update?

Fix released, 20.04 fixed with 21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.10 xorg-server package.
sudo apt --fix-broken install && sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

After updating to fix version still have Xorg crashes when working with IDEA 1-2 times per day.
apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-core shows:
2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.17ppa15 500 (hotkeys fix patch)
2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.17 500 (official)
2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2 500 (previous)
Why there is no earlier versions to downgrade?

@MainActivity Are you sure you have the same error? There was a problem in version xserver-xorg-core_1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.16 with fonts. Versions .15 and .17 don't have this bug. If you have version .17 there's no need to downgrade. Make sure you have xserver-common and xwayland in correct versions. Also check if you don't have broken packages.

"go back to previous versions" helped, no fix is found on 22.04 on 04.05.2024.

@emoxam If "apt upgrade" doesn't resolve the problem I guess you have broken packages. There is a fix on Ubuntu 22.04 since 10.04.2024. I use Ubuntu 22.04 and I checked it work.

@emoxam Check "apt upgrade" output message.

@artur what version of what app helped to fix this isuue ?

@artur pycharm stop crashing xorg server while you are trying to search for 'journal' via shift_shift ?

@emoxam
"what version of what app helped to fix this isuue"
Java apps using font antialiasing. We had problems with IntelliJ and our own Java app. Pycharm uses the same engine, so it's also effected.
We uses Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 and both are effected. In case of Ubuntu 22.04 xorg-core...9, common...9 and xwayland...12 causes error. Make sure to upgrade (or downgrade) all 3 files.
Info about the bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/2060354

@artur playing with AA options at pycharm doesn't help. here's my bug report,  can i upgrade something to fix it ? xorg-server. xwayland ? Now it's latest https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/2065172

@artur I got error about pixman creating radial gradients, other parts of log https://0x0.st/X84_.txt are same and this error appeared after last xorg update

As i told there is no fix with update on xserver-xorg-core or xserver-common or xwayland. Only downgrade helps. Don't know what fix on ubuntu helped @arthur, and he don't tell us what packet update helped him to fix pycharm issue.
Maybe update to xwayland - 2:23.2.0-1ubuntu0.6 will help but i can't find out how to update to this version.
Btw. after downgrading only xserver-xorg-core founds update.
xserver-xorg-core/jammy-security,jammy-updates,now 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.10 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.10ppa11]

So i don't think xwayland - 2:23.2.0-1ubuntu0.6 will helped me.

@emoxam "helped arthur, and he don't tell us what packet update helped him to fix pycharm issue". Read what I wrote - I don't use pycharm. People in this thread confirm that downgrade is not needed any more. OFFICIAL 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.11 and 22.04.10 work BUT you use UNOFFICIAL PERSONAL version from https://launchpad.net/~nrbrtx repository. I don't know what is in his codes and if they work. Official current version (11) and previous official version (10) work. There was a problem in official version 9 xorg-core. Also, Xserver-common and xwayland need to be change.

@artur How can be sure it is fixed? What changelog string talks about fixing this issue ?

As I said... https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/2060354

@artur You are right, i forget that i am using launchpad.net/~nrbrtx repo, or maybe that's my issue because i am linux Nube ) I asked nrbrtx to update their repo too and seems it fixed at nrbrtx  repo too. Thanks!

artur answer worked for me! (Ubuntu 23.10, fresh upgraded from 22.04 trying to solve that issue).
As I use KDE instead of Gnome, I just bypassed dependency check of xwayland_1.20.13 with libmutter-13-0 using --ignore-depends parameter on dpkg, and it worked after reboot.
dpkg --ignore-depends=libmutter-13-0 -i xwayland_22.1.1-1ubuntu0.11_amd64.deb

thanks for confirming. i saw your issue submission to intellij issue tracker and both the issue described and the log were identical to mine, although im running ubuntu 22.04 and the issue happened in a specific place and in a very specific file layout preview in android studio. so far the solution works for me as well

I was having similar issues with Android Studio (also based on IntelliJ). My xorg stacktrace seems identical to yours.
In my case, the fix was to change the editor font rendering from Greyscale back to Subpixel. This can be done without starting the IDE, by manually editing the XML configuration:

For IntelliJ: ~/.config/JetBrains/<your_version>/options/other.xml
For Android Studio: ~/.config/Google/<your_version>/options/other.xml

In both cases, you need to remove the line that reads:
<option name="editorAAType" value="Greyscale" />

I guess a similar one could be present if you (also) used Greyscale font rendering for the IDE, this was not my case.

Thank you for your response, I couldn't check if this answer is correct because I already solved the issue using @artur's answer. But I can confirm that I am using Greyscale antialiasing, and that line is present in my options file. So it is possible that this solution could have helped me as well.

Had the same Issue and resolved it in the same way.
Here is the youtrack report https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-350864/Idea.sh-abort-X-window

I don't have any lines with Greyscale in it.  Though I'm not running Ubuntu, Manjaro instead, but how can it be different there.  I ended up reverting packages xorg-xwayland, xorg-server, and xorg-server-common to the previous version.

I had the same problem with PhpStorm 2024.1.1 on Ubuntu 24.04 that crashed when opening an .md file.
Their official website mentions a workaround:
https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/18686026533394/comments/18843472654994
That workaround worked fine for me. After adding -Dide.browser.jcef.sandbox.enable=false to ~/.config/JetBrains/PhpStorm2024.1/PhpStorm64.vmoptions I was able to open .md files in PhpStorm again.

For Ubuntu 22.04 and IntelliJ 2024.1 changing the antialiasing settings for IDE and Editor worked for me.
The change does not requires to start the IDE, just go in
~/.config/JetBrains/<your_version>/options/other.xml

and remove the lines
<option name="ideAAType" value="Greyscale" />
<option name="editorAAType" value="Greyscale" />

in order to select the default antialiasing (Subpixel)

For manjaro users
I had this issue with xorg-server 21.1.12
downgrading to 21.1.11 helped:
sudo manjaro-downgrade xorg-server 


I know I am a bit late to the party, but here are my two cents.
It seems many people recently have been having the issue described here since last IDEA Ultimate updates (2024.1 and 2024.1.1), that resulted in semi-random crashes when loading/updating the code suggestions popup window that appears when you type code.
If your /var/log/syslog has a line containing OGLTR_DrawGlyphList.part, then maybe, as suggested in the thread, until a permanent fix is released you could try to add the following line to your ~/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2024.1/idea64.vmoptions:
-Dsun.java2d.opengl=false

Hope this helps. It worked for me.

For Ubuntu 23.10 the following helps me to fix the issue(temporary):

Go to the XML configuration(for IntelliJ):
~/.config/JetBrains/<your_version>/options/other.xml


And remove exactly two lines:
<option name="ideAAType" value="Greyscale" />
<option name="editorAAType" value="Greyscale" />



